# Angular Firestore security rules

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to query a collection of city names which has the city's name as the document ID, and a single field in the document called "count" which is incremented by a cloud function.

However when I try to query this data, I'm told insufficient permissions by Firebase.

Here's the code that queries Firestore

```
    db = firebase.firestore()
  async getCities() {
    var docRef = await this.db.collection("Cities").orderBy("count", "desc").limit(10)
      .get()
      .then(function(querySnapshot){
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
          console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());

        })
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });
```

I'm a bit confused because the rules playground indicates this query should be allowed.

Here's the section of my rules that the playground says is allowing my read

```
match /Cities/{docId} {
  allow get;
}
```

Or is it because I'm trying to read a subset of the collection?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the security rules from false to true,that's what happend to me when I wanted to post data to the Firestore database